# ArrayList is empty in other Methods in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

The ArrayList is initialised inside a Class and its values are set in a method (which are only existent in this method)

How could I prevent the arraylist from being empty or why is this even happening?

(Edit: I added this minor project to github (https://github.com/goodstuff20/NENAM))

```
List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>(); 

public Creature(Node[] nodes){
    for(int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        this.nodes.add(nodes[i]); 
    }  
    System.out.println(this.nodes.size()); //4
}

public void tick(){  
    System.out.println(nodes.size()); //0 
}
```

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: You can put your code, which used the this code?

Comment: There's not enough context in your code sample.  You need to show how the class is defined, and whether or not `tick()` is a member of `class Creature`, and how `Creature` is instantiated and how `tick()` is invoked.

Comment: Are you sure that you are re-using the same instance of `Creature`?  Are there any other methods called before `tick()` is called which could change the state?

Comment: No there is nothing that manually changes or clears the arraylist. When I create a new integer for example and set it to 2 (in the constructor  and print this), then print its value in the tick method the output is 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 etc

Comment: (Not sure what ask is, did I guess correctly?)  If you want to be sure you Never get a Creature with empty nodes then you could require a non-empty nodes argument for the Creature constructor by adding a check like this at the beginning of your constructor: e.g. if( nodes == null || nodes.isEmpty() ) { throw new RuntimeException("Creature() must have 1 or more node!"); }     All your Creature constructors would need to enforce that condition.  And if using a RuntimeException is not to your liking, consider building a CreatureMustHaveNonEmptyNodes exceptions (which seems like overkill to me).

Comment: @jgreve uh no didnt mean that :D -> um in the constructor I fillup the nodes with "information" (which are filled when I check btw), but the same creature looses this information outside of its constructor i.e. when the tick method gets called ...

Answer (score 0):

You have defined 2 contructors in class Creature. In the second ctor you make a call to the first using the new-operator:

```
public Creature(Node[] nodes){
    //....
    for(int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
        nodess.add(nodes[i]);
    }
    //....

}

public Creature(int[][] nodePos, int[][] musclePos){ 
    //...
    Node[] nodes = new Node[nodePos.length]; 
    //...
    new Creature(nodes);
}
```

Maybe your intention is to change the currently created object by calling the other ctor, but instead you create a new object with no relation to the first.
To call another ctor inside a ctor on the same object you have to use `this`, but that must be done in the first line.
For example:

```
public Creature(int[][] nodePos, int[][] musclePos){ 
    this(...);
}
```

For your purposes it is better to use an init-method:

```
public Creature(Node[] nodes){
    init(nodes);
}

public Creature(int[][] nodePos, int[][] musclePos){ 
    //...
    Node[] nodes = new Node[nodePos.length]; //when defineing an int length = normal and not -1
    //...
    init(nodes);
}
private void init(Node[] nodes) {

    //...
    for(int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
        nodess.add(nodes[i]);
    }
    //...
}
```